# Error when installing XLRD using pip for python (3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip, python-3.6

I am using windows 10 64-bit and i installed pip as well as python using the python installer. When i type the command `pip install xlrd` the following error appears :

```
C:\Users\Tanmay>pip install xlrd
Collecting xlrd
  Downloading xlrd-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (143kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 317kB/s
Installing collected packages: xlrd
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\xlrd'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got fixed simply by running the command prompt as an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

it gives you Permission Error try to install it 
as super user `sudo pip install xlrd`

in case of windows, in cmd try to run pip install using python executable

e.g.

```
`python -m pip install xlrd`
```

Comment: This is windows